# How can I tell in te python file that I want to draw the spinners on top of my ScrollView but not in the box layout?

Tags: python, kivy, spinner

```
<WindowManager>:
    FirstWindow:
    
    
    SecondWindow:



<FirstWindow>:
    name: "menu"
    
    canvas.before:    
        Color:
            rgba: (242/255, 202/255, 5/255, 1)        
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: [55]
    
    
    Image: 
        source: 'Logoapp.png'
   

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        size: 50, 50    
        Button:
            font_size: 20
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
            
            pos:100, 400
            background_color: 0,0,0,0
            text: "Cotizar"
            color: 0,0,0,1
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: (23/255,152/255,216/255,0.71)
                RoundedRectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
                    radius:[55]

            on_release: 
                app.root.current = "cotiza"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"


<SecondWindow>:
    
    id: Ventana
    name: "cotiza"
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (148/255,193/255,255/255,1)
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius:[55]
    
    
    
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        spacing: 10
        Spinner:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 100, 40
            id: 'RUC'
            text: "RUC"
            values: ['20555949457', '2058474586', '1025874658']
        ScrollView:
            do_scroll_x: False
            do_scroll_y: True
            FloatLayout: 
                id:Listadespl
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: (255/255, 206/255,53/255,1)
                    RoundedRectangle:
                        size: self.size
                        pos: self.pos
                        radius: [55]
                size_hint: (1, None)
                height: 2000
                orientation:'vertical'                
        Button:
            font_size: 12
            size: 50, 50 
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.3
            pos_hint: {"x":.7}
            background_color: 0,0,0,0
            text: "+"
            color: 0,0,0,1
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: (23/255,152/255,216/255,0.71)
                RoundedRectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    radius:[20]
                    pos: self.pos
            on_press: root.pressiona(self)
                
from sqlite3.dbapi2 import DatabaseError
from sys import path
from types import SimpleNamespace, new_class
from kivy.app import App
import asyncio
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget 
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner, SpinnerOption

from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle, RoundedRectangle

import sqlite3
import json
import os

Window.size = (250, 500 ) #Cambiamos el tamaño de la ventana para simular un celular

from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class FirstWindow(Screen, FloatLayout):
   pass
    
class MySpinner(Spinner, Widget):

    


    def __init__(self, valores, **kwargs):
        super(MySpinner, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
        
                  
                        

                        

        
       

    

    def movable(self):
        
        
        pass
        
        #Creamos los labels de precio y descripcion
            # self.LabelPrec = Label()     
            # self.LabelDesc = Label()
            # self.LabelDesc.pos =  
    
  
            # self.LabelPrec.pos.x = self.pos.x + 30
    

        






class SecondWindow(Screen, FloatLayout):

    conn = sqlite3.connect("inventingt.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""SELECT Codigo FROM masterinv """)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    listcode = [str(t[0]) for t in rows] 
    childsid = ListProperty([])
    
    
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(SecondWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
            
            
            #Creamos la conexion a la base de datos
            
            Spinners = []

            
            s = int(input("introduce un valor"))

            print(SecondWindow.ids)
            for i in range(s):
                    objects = [Spinner()]
                    Spinners.extend(objects)
                    if i+1 == s:
                        for j in Spinners:
                            print("estoy entrando a spinners")
                            j.size_hint = None,None
                            j.pos = (20,300)
                            j.background_color = [255, 255, 255, 1]
                            j.text = "Prueba"
                            j.color = [0, 0, 0, 1]
                            j.size = (100,44)
                            j.values = self.listcode
                            self.add_widget(j)
                            for h in Spinners[1:s]:
                                (a, b) = h.pos
                                a = a
                                b = b + 60
                                h.pos = (a,b)
                                print(h)
                                    
                    
            print(Spinners)
```

> > I Instantiate my spinners and given position, but I want to specifically draw these spinners on top of the floating layout that contains the scroll view, not before which is actually doing the program when I build it. I've done the object property thing and tried to link it within the kv file but doesn't work, like a float layout = ObjectProperty(None), then in the same KV File within the Float Layout given the reference to it, but I cannot manipulate it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Just to note. Your `MySpinner` should not extend `Widget`, since `Spinner` is already a `Widget`. Similarly, your `FirstWindow` and `SecondWindow` should not extend `FloatLayout`, since `Screen` is already a `RelativeLayout`. Doing that can only cause problems. Also, if you intend to use `ids`, you cannot do so in the `__init__()` method because `ids` are not yet available there.

Comment: Thank u so much for your response, I will delete this from my classes, and yes it makes so much sense that the ids will not be available there since is the initialization of everything, so I think I have to access them through the build method of my app?

Comment: Or you can just add a `Clock.schedule_once()` in the `__init__()` method to schedule another method.